# JUnit testing failure - Must be known Item Number

Tags: java, arrays, list, methods, junit

My Junit testing keeps failing and saying `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: must be known item number` I've tried multiple different ways of testing it but can't find a solution. It seems that it can't find the item number I am entering but as you can see from the main class, item number '1' with all the other details are there and match!

Class I'm testing:

```
package Purchase; 


import java.util.*;
public class ItemStore implements saveItem {     

    private class saveDescriptor {
        int itemNumber;


        assert !isKnownItemNumber(itemNumber) : "must not be used item number";
        assert unitPrice > 0 : "price must be positive";
        assert sort == 0 || sort == 1 : "sort must be 0 or 1";
        assert !description.trim().equals("") : "description must not be
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils everything else runs perfectly, just my testing won't pass for some reason. I am new to Junit so I'm unsure if i am doing the tests incorrect.

Comment: Put in some debug print statements or run through the code with a debugger, and figure out where it's falling down.  See also http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Your main method and the test class have nothing to do with each other. You'll have to create and populate an `ItemStore` for the each test (possibly in your `setUp` method if you want to use the same fixture for each test).

EDIT:

The test class and your GUI application are two completely different programs. In the GUI program, you added some records to your `ItemStore`:

```
ItemStore.newItems.recordItem(1,"Banana", 1.00, 1);
ItemStore.newItems.recordItem(2, "Tv", 250.00, 0);
ItemStore.newItems.recordItem(3, "Carrots", 0.75, 1);
```

These items exist in this program. In your test class, you do not have any lines that look like this. Try this for your first test:

```
@Test
public void testIsKnownItemNumber() {
    System.out.println("isKnownItemNumber");
    int itemNumber = 1;
    ItemStore.newItems.recordItem(1, "Banana", 1.00, 1);
    ItemStore instance = new ItemStore();
    boolean expResult = true;
    boolean result = instance.isKnownItemNumber(itemNumber);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

I would also get rid of `testRecordItem` since it doesn't actually test anything. Get rid of the static `newItem` list as well, and make it an instance field of the `ItemStore`. This might be why some of your tests may have been passing: if all the tests run in the same JVM, that test is impacting the state seen by all of the other tests that run after it. Tests should be self contained.

Comment: so in the setup method i would need to create the array lists??

Comment: You would need to add your three record items to the `ItemStore`, otherwise your tests are trying to find items in an empty `ItemStore`.

Comment: how do i add them to ItemStore, i thought they were already stored there?